# bash replace string by 4-digit hex code

Tags: bash, sed, utf-8, hex

I have strings:

`^[U0422^Z ^[U041D^Z^[U0410^Z ^[U0412^Z^[U042B^Z^[U0417^Z === Т НА ВЫЗ`

etc. And I want do sed on that string, to replace the codes ^[Uxxxx^Z

How can I do this if sed only accept 2-digit hex codes? I have 3 GB data with characters encoded like this... I need do this in script, because I have multiple files and 152 characters to decode...

Comment: Replace with what?

Comment: Is what's on the left side some known encoding? What bytes are in the data? I guess ^[ is the escape character, not two characters, but what is U0422?

Comment: Replace with code from pattern. ^[ and ^Z are escape codes, U0422 is Unicode character, U+0422 https://unicode-table.com/en/#0422

I must replace ^[U0422^Z with unicode character with code 0422. All files are in utf-8 encoding but some characters are stored as unicode code literally...

Comment: What do you mean replace "unicode character with code 0422"? It's already code 0422. Do you mean ^[U0422^Z should become 0422, or the actual character "T"? It's unclear by how you describe it.

Comment: And, this isn't must be with sed... I tried with perl with good results, but perl change other good characters in file to wrong :/ For example, in file I have 2 lines: `Moje hobby piłka nożna` - with is good (text in Polish) and second line is `Moli^[U00E8^Zre` with is wrong and should be `Molière` (è is U+00E8). My perl script replace ^[UXXXX^Z with good characters, but saves file with bad encoding of good characters. Now `Moje hobby piłka nożna` is `Moje hobby piÅ<82>ka noÅ¼na` with is bad... -Mopen:utf8 is not working

Comment: @l'L'l ALL series, ^[U0422^Z should be replaced by character `Т` which is Unicode character U+0422. And sorry for my English...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `perl`, here's an example:

**file.txt**:

```
Żelazna ręka Marsa - J^[U00F8^Zrstad, Jarl. ^[U0422^Z ^[U041D^Z^[U0410^Z ^[U0412^Z^[U042B^Z^[U0417^Z
```

**script.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open my $in,  '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $ARGV[1] or die $!;

while (<$in>) {
    $_ =~ s/\^\[U([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})\^Z/sprintf "%c", hex($1)/ge;
    print $out $_; 
}

close $in;
close $out;
```

Syntax is `./script.pl <input> <output>`.

**output**:

```
$ ./script.pl
Żelazna ręka Marsa - Jørstad, Jarl. Т НА ВЫЗ
```

**recursive version**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @files = <*.txt>;
 for my $file (@files) {

  open my $in,  '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file or die $!;
  open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $ARGV[0] . "_" . $file or die $!;

  while (<$in>) {
    $_ =~ s/\^\[U([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})\^Z/sprintf "%c", hex($1)/ge;
    print $out $_; 
 }
close $in;
close $out;
}
```

Syntax is `./script.pl <prefix>`. If data.txt was found the new file would be prefix_data.txt.

Comment: OK, this is good, but check this script with file:
```Żelazna ręka Marsa - J^[U00F8^Zrstad, Jarl.```
and in output should be:
```Żelazna ręka Marsa - Jørstad, Jarl.```

Comment: Try this one: `sed -Ee 's/\^[Z\^]//g' -Ee 's/\^\[U/\\u/g'`, that should handle it better. The word `ręka` though comes out to be `rÄka` for some reason or another in my terminal.

Comment: And one more, `^[` and `^Z` are escape characters. There aren't two separate characters, they are one escape code, one ^[ and one ^Z. They act as start point and end point of Unicode character representation. And in perl I have command `perl -CIOE -p -e 's/^[U([\dA-F]{4})^Z/sprintf "%c", hex($1)/ge' ${file} > ${file}.new`

Comment: Yep, you're right about that. This should probably do it `perl -CIOE -p -e 's/\^\[U([\dA-F]{4})\^Z/sprintf "%c", hex($1)/ge'`

Comment: My code is working, I remind, ^[ and ^Z are control codes, not normal characters, so they are good in my code. My code is working, but now I have problem with encoding other before-script good characters. Before executing script, there is `ręka` and after is `rÄka` which is bad... And I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: Yes, I noticed that with `ręka` before also, although using only the `perl` to handle everything it's normal now in my terminal. If you do `echo "Żelazna ręka Marsa - J^[U00F8^Zrstad, Jarl." | perl -CIOE -p -e 's/\^\[U([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})\^Z/sprintf "%c", hex($1)/ge' ` does the output look normal?

Comment: Then you should be able to use that with `> file.txt` and I would imagine it should work.

Comment: But when I use it with input from file and output to file, there is wrong char... I use it with `.../ge' input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: I think I've got it sorted for you — check the edit.

Comment: Yay! It's working! Now I only need to parametrize this, so I can run script with path to folder and file extension, like `./script.pl ../data/*.txt` and script should read *.txt file and save new file .txt.new

Comment: @Nolias: There are now two versions, the first is for single files (syntax: `./script.pl input.txt output.txt`), the second version will recursively go through all files of a certain type `.txt`, (syntax: `./script.pl new`). For example if you had a file in the directory named `data.txt` it would add the prefix "new" onto it becoming `new_data.txt`.